# Cannot get access token of box api > "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"

Tags: box-api

No matter whether I use:

```
https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=OS9wgZP1NkP9e7R7cLbpfnTlMJLCwyIn&client_id=*******&client_secret=*********
```

or if I use:

```
curl -k https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=OS9wgZP1NkP9e7R7cLbpfnTlMJLCwyIn&client_id=**********&client_secret=******' -X POST
```

I always get:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you specified a redirect_uri when you configured your application?